# Redirect sub-paths to different destinations in kubernetes nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to redirect traffic from an older version of my site to the newer version of the site. Although, I have these 2 specific requirements. I need:

1. `old.mysite.com/` to be redirected to `new.mysite.com/homepage`.
2. All the other sub paths to be redirected as is to the new site. Ex: `old.mysite.com/this/sub/path` should be redirected to `new.mysite.com/this/sub/path`

I am using the kubernetes nginx ingress controller and I am currently using configuration-snippets to redirect all the traffic from old to new site like this:

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  if ($host = "old.mysite.com")
  {
    return 301 https://new.mysite.com$request_uri;
  }
```

Is there a way to modify this to fit my requirement or is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: Have you tried using two conditions:
```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  if ($host = "old.mysite.com")
  {
    return 301 https://new.mysite.com/homepage;
  }
  if ($host = "old.mysite.com")
  {
    return 301 https://new.mysite.com$request_uri;
  }
```

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I tried this and it works for the 1st requirement, but all the other paths are getting redirected to `new.mysite.com/homepage` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by combining server snippet along with your configuration snippet.

This will match to the default `/` URI and do the redirection.

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
     location = / {
      rewrite ^ https://new.mysite.com/homepage permanent;
      break;
     }
```